# New FUITableViewDataSource - how to use? Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Just updated to the newer FirebaseUI Pod - a few things have changed but one of the big ones is the way that the FUI Table View works. I had it working well on an older version but am struggling with this below - and the lack of documentation/examples.

```
 self.dataSource = FUITableViewDataSource(query: <#T##FIRDatabaseQuery#>, view: <#T##UITableView#>, populateCell: <#T##(UITableView, IndexPath, FIRDataSnapshot) -> UITableViewCell#>)
```

I don't understand where the indexpath is being called from. Do I need to make a seperate `NSIndexPath` to pass into that? I also don't really understand where this is supposed to live - previously, with it was `FirebaseTableViewDataSource`, I would set it in my `viewDidLoad`, and it would create the cells etc straight from that. It almost now looks as though it needs to live in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Does anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [test](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseDatabaseUITests/FUITableViewDataSourceTest.m) for this latest version uses a tableView:bind: method (seems like a UITableView class extension they made) and I was able to get it to work.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let firebaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(/*insert path for list here*/)

    let query = firebaseRef.queryOrderedByKey() /*or a more sophisticated query of your choice*/

    let dataSource = self.tableView.bind(to: query, populateCell: { (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) -> UITableViewCell in

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        let someProp = value["someProp"] as? String ?? ""

        cell.textLabel?.text = someProp

        return cell
    })
}
```

Also make sure you are observing your query for changes or else the tableView won't get populated

```
self.query?.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
})
```

Comment: It's not working for me, can you point me to a working sample