# What is the iOS version of firebase list adapter?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to populate a data in view controller without reloadData() after save in firebase manually, likewise in android i have used firebase list adapter which is responsible for binding as well as reloading. want to do the same is swift4 and jsqmessagesviewcontroller. Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is:

> `FUITableViewDataSource`
>
> Data source to bind a Firebase query to a UITableView

Equivalent for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:

> `FUICollectionViewDataSource`
>
> Data source to bind a Firebase query to a UICollectionView

more info here:

[FirebaseUI for IOS](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI)

Comment: Sir, Thanks For your valuable help. but can you tell me exactly how to use FUITableViewDataSource. i follow this link- FirebaseUI for IOS, but it was not clear to me

Comment: here check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855215/new-fuitableviewdatasource-how-to-use-swift-3

Comment: Done it accordingly

Comment: @GoribDeveloper If you're having a problem getting the example code working, open a new question that shows the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).